# Unable to go inside a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to upload and retrieve data from firebase into my web app but the problem I am encountering now is that I am unable to do so now, the thing to be noted here is that I was able to do that before. The problem lies that the application isn't going inside the function where the retrieval code is written

below is my code snippet:-
HTML CODE-

```
  </div>
  <div>
   <ul id="data" class="ulData">
    <li>

    </li>

  </ul>
</div>





<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBj-iSnd9fLeQlaeEvrKC3ZAh1L5k9CG6I",
    authDomain: "blog-783b4.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://blog-783b4.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "blog-783b4",
    storageBucket: "blog-783b4.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "163768535060"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>    
<script src="read.js"></script>
```

Javascript-

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");
alert("entering the function");
rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
    alert("inside the functions.");
    var key = snap.key;
    var title = snap.child("Title").val();
    var desc = snap.child("desc").val();
    console.log(title);
    $("#data").append(`<li><div class="w">
        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="${key}">${title}</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" id="descPost">
            ${desc}
          </div>
        </div></li>`
    );
}
);
alert("outside the functions.");
```

The alert for entering the function is displayed and the alert for outside the function is also there but the alert for inside the function isn't displayed which only means that the application isn't going inside the function.

Please have a look.

Comment: You say you were able to do that before. Before what? Can you be more specific? Did you change something? Did you update something?

Comment: nothing much I just tried to add the functionality for image upload to firebase but that didn't go well, so I removed the code but ever since neither am I able to upload or retrieve data from the firebase. I have completely removed the image functionality code but still, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you have any data in the database? If not, you need to add something for the `.on('child_added',...)` to trigger. It will trigger when you add data and for data already in the database. Is any of these your case?

Comment: yeah, I know that I have data in the database which I uploaded through the application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the mobile event to start your function , For example this one when u touch the screen,

Hope will help u,

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ // on page load

    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        alert('Hiii ok') // replace with your function
    }, false)

}, false)
```